# Angular JS $http post with get params in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I am having trouble with posting to a URL with GET parameters using Angular's $http.

URL: `http://localhost/api/?r=page/product`

Now I have to post data to this URL via AJAX. When I try it with the following code it doesn't work.

```
$http({
    url:'api/?r=page/product',
    method:'post',
    params:{
       price:$scope.price
    },
});
```

Where as the same in jQuery Works flawlessly.

```
$.ajax({
 url:'api/?r=page/product',
 method:'post',
 data:{
    price:$scope.price
 }
});
```

What should I add to make it work?

Regards

Comment: could you try specifying header in the `$http` option `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}`

Comment: @PankajParkar sir I suppose the default header will be set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` if we donn't set any header with the request. Is it wrong sir ?

Comment: @PankajParkar it is already what you said...

Comment: @PankajParkar You are right its not `url-encoded` its `json object`

Comment: @echo_salik it works without header **OR** you requires to add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$http({
    url:'/api',
    method:'post',
    params: {
       r: 'page/product'
    },
    data:{
       price:$scope.price
    },
});
```

you mixed up params with data, params are the query parameters added to the url, data is the data being sent in the request

Comment: still going to generate the same url. Don't see how this changes anything

Comment: he has put the data ($scope.params) to the params, that is why the behavior is different to the one from jQuery

Comment: @alekkowalczyk Thanks it does the trick... but the data being sent is not what a normal post looks like. Its like a JSON object.

Comment: @alekkowalczyk nice catch